# Returning maximum value between rows when a certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Fruits': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple'],
    'Price': [20, 30, 50, 170, 55, 90]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Max']=0
df['Max']=df['Max'].astype(float)
for x in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    condition=(df['Fruits']=="Apple")&(df['Fruits'].shift(-1)=="Apple")|(df['Fruits'].shift(1)=="Apple")
    df.loc[condition,'Max']=df.loc[condition,'Price'].max()`
```

```
Fruits  Price   Max
0   Apple   20  90.0
1   Apple   30  90.0
2   Banana  50  90.0
3   Orange  170 0.0
4   Apple   55  90.0
5   Apple   90  90.0
```

I want max value for first 2 apples as 30 and last 2 apple as 90. How do I achieve it?
Also please clarify why 90 is returned in the Banana value row as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's the "certain condition" you're talking about? adjacent groups of "apple"? In that case, this existing question should help: [How to groupby consecutive values in pandas DataFrame](/q/40802800/4518341). Otherwise, please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. Regarding the banana max, isn't it obvious? `df['Fruits'].shift(1)=="Apple"`

Comment: Yep I had given df['Fruits'].shift(1)=="Apple" , 
before that I had given  (df['Fruits']=="Apple"), doesn't this mean condition should be applied only if the Fruits is equal to apple?

Comment: Oh, you just need parentheses around the `|` expression. If it helps, see [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
grp =  df.Fruits.ne(df.Fruits.shift()).cumsum()
df['Max'] = df.groupby(grp)['Price'].transform('max')
df
   Fruits  Price  Max
0   Apple     20   30
1   Apple     30   30
2  Banana     50   50
3  Orange    170  170
4   Apple     55   90
5   Apple     90   90
```

Comment: This works as expected. Thank you very much @Onyambu.

Comment: @Starlord consider accepting the solution, by clickcling on the checkmark against the solution. In that way it willhelp others too who face the same issue. Also conside upvoting